# Angular 4 keyup.enter not working properly

Tags: angular, angular4-forms

I trigger addComment function on keyup.enter and click event.
and I have applied if condition in addComment function that if ngModel value comment tends to be empty or undefined then I would alert an error. But as in case I write code for keyup.enter then my validation stops working. console.log prints nothing at all and check does not work.
This happens for keyup.enter and not for click event.
Please suggest some fix.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
<div style="margin-left: 30px; margin-top: 1%;" class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12">

    <textarea style="border-radius: 20px;display:inline!important;" (keyup.enter)="addComment($event)" [(ngModel)]="comment" class="form-control" placeholder="Add Comment">

    </textarea>
  <button (click)="addComment($event)" style="display:inline-block;margin-top: 2%" class="btn-success">Add Comment</button>
</div>
</div>
```

**Component**

```
import {Component, OnInit, ElementRef, ViewChild, Renderer2} from '@angular/core';
import { CommentsDataService} from "../../services/comments/comments-data.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list-comments',
  templateUrl: './list-comments.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list-comments.component.css']
})
export class ListCommentsComponent implements OnInit {
  commentsData; // Json array of Comment Data received from service.
  comment:string; // Commennt text; declaration.
  postId = 1;
  getComments;  // Declaration of function.




  @ViewChild('commentData.id') commentDataId;  // id of reply textarea


  /**
   * Append new comment
   * @param comment
   */
  addComment(comment)
  {
    console.log("comment text:"+this.comment);
    if(typeof this.comment == "undefined" || this.comment === '' || this.comment == null)
    {
      alert("Add some text!");
      return false;
    }
    else
    {

      this.commentsData.push({

        root_id:"2",
        target_id: "12",
        text: this.comment,
        comment_posted_by:"Jack",
        comment_posted_by_image:'../../assets/images/no-user.png'
      })
    }



  }

  addReply();
  addReply()
  {
    var textarea = this.commentDataId.nativeElement;

    alert(this.commentDataId);



  }

  constructor(private commentsDataService:CommentsDataService, private renderer: Renderer2 ) {





  }



  ngOnInit() {

    this.commentsData = this.commentsDataService.getComments(this.postId);
     console.log( this.commentsData)


  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**1. check does not work:**

Actually the problem is that you are not checking with the **empty new line**. If you press enter key a new line is generated in the textarea and it will not match up with your conditions.

```
if(typeof this.comment == "undefined" || this.comment === '' || this.comment == null){ }
```

In your **if** conditions there is no checking for the empty new line. that's why it is going to the else case.

just try this,

```
if(typeof this.comment == "undefined" || this.comment === '' || this.comment == null || this.comment == '\n'){  }
```

For the first time enter key press you can see the deference. But I am strongly suggesting you that don't use the above condition as such. That is just for your understanding only.

**2.console.log prints nothing at all**

For a new line we cannot see anything in the console or alert message.

Answer (score 0):

Use this it will take care of all the conditions

```
 if( this.comment  ) {
    }
```

> will evaluate to true if the value is not:

null
 undefined
 NaN
 empty string ("")
 0
 false